# Hyper-V VM on a Different Machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hal

I was just reading some articles on Hyper-V and one says it interacts with the machine's hardware, and doesn't need to be over top of a host OS.

Does that mean if I were to export a copy, I couldn't import it on different hardware because of the HAL?

Thanks.

Comment: You do understand the reason, you cannot boot Windows on different machines isn't because of the HAL, right?

Comment: @Ramhound So why can't I boot on different hardware?  In general terms.

Comment: I am not prepared to list the dozen or so reasons Windows isn't as forgiving as Linux when it comes to booting on different hardware.  At the end of the day, Windows treats devices differently then Linux does, and expects devices to be there if it detected them in the past.  You can easily tell Windows, yep I am moving this installation to another machine, and it will then boot.  Activation of Windows at that point, is up to you, to provide a valid license though.  Your question(s) don't indicate you have done enough research.